# Why is my RigidBody2D not moving in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, movement

My problem is when I am pressing <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd>, the player does not move. It is very stupid I am sure as you are, but I can not find what I am doing wrong. I could have achieved the effect I want with the help of `transform.translate()`, but I would like immensely to get what is misunderstood by me in the case.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float runningSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D playerBody;

    void Update ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            print("Right");
            moveRight();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            print("Left");
            moveLeft();
        }
    }

    private void moveLeft()
    {
        playerBody.AddForce(Vector2.left * (runningSpeed * Time.deltaTime), ForceMode2D.Force);
    }

    private void moveRight()
    {
        playerBody.AddForce(Vector2.right * (runningSpeed*Time.deltaTime), ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my editor:

[image]

Comment: Don't happen to have any constraints set, do you?

Comment: @Byte56, no. I checked right now, there are no any constraints.

Comment: Tried using Vector3 instead of Vector2 does not work either. Tried using AddForce() without second parameter does not work as well.

Comment: Possible solution for this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/rigidbody-addforce-not-moving-the-object.539865/#post-3559413 Answer 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. Unity considers Mass of 10 to be very large. First I tried to apply a very great force, like 10 thousand and noticed that `RigidBody2D` actually moves a little bit. Then I decreased Mass to 0.5 and voila I got a needed effect!

Answer (score -1):

Your force depends linearly on "runningSpeed", so if the initial velocity is zero, it will stay zero. Try to give a different intial speed or change your force.

Comment: Reason for the downvote?

Comment: The screenshot shows a non-zero running speed, and running speed is not set from the object's initial velocity in any code we can see here.